# canonical-livepatch won't run due to apparmor permission denied error

Tags: apparmor, canonical-livepatch

```
$ canonical-livepatch
cannot change apparmor hat of the support process for mount namespace capture. errmsg: Operation not permitted
support process for mount namespace capture exited abnormally
```

It's the same error with or without `sudo`. Ubuntu 16.04.1 server.

I have two Ubuntu desktops as well with 16.04 and they had no problems.

Comment: Oddly I can't reproduce the error anymore. It seems to have magically fixed itself.